# How to return multiple values from lodash _.times?

Tags: reactjs, lodash

For some reason, my lodash method `_.times` doesn't work. It won't give `col` value for the other function I'm calling, even though I'm giving it in the `_.times` method.

```
// shownNews is a data-table, pulled from the database. 

return (
  <>
    <AddNews/>
    {_.times(shownNews.length, (col) =>
      <Info
        key={col}
        shownNews={shownNews}
        col={shownNews.length - 1 - col}
      />,
      <ReadMore
        shownNews={shownNews}
        col={col} // this gives me an error, col not found
      />
    )}
  </>
);
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You want to generate `Info` & `ReadMore` `col` number of times? You want to generate both separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official documentation, it is mentioned that [_.times](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#times) accepts a function in second parameter. Whereas in your case, you are passing 3 parameters.

I tried following in REPL(replicating your scenario):

```
_.times(3, (index) => JSON.stringify(index*2), JSON.stringify(index*3));
```

I got error: `ReferenceError: index is not defined` in third parameter.

It is not clear from question what you are trying to achieve but if you want 
both `Info` & `ReadMore` together, use `Fragment` as shown below:

```
{_.times(shownNews.length, (col) =>
  <Fragment key={col}>
    <Info
      shownNews={shownNews}
      col={shownNews.length - 1 - col}
    />
    <ReadMore
      shownNews={shownNews}
      col={col} // this gives me an error, col not found
    />
  </Fragment>
)}
```

or if you want `Info` & `ReadMore` separately, use `_.times` 2 times.

Comment: Wow, just wow... I thought I tried that already, but it works! Only difference I made was putting `<Fragment key={col}>` instead of `<>`, as it makes the unique child (error goes away at least). Thank you!

Comment: Welcome... Happy to help.